# Central limit theorem for distribution peak rather than mean

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

The central limit theorem states that the arithmetic mean of a sufficiently large number of iterates of independent random variables, each with a well-defined expected value and well-defined variance, will be approximately normally distributed. i.e.

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}
   \sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_i X_i - \mu\right)
   = \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2).
$$

My question is whether a similar result exists which allows for some combinations of samples to tend towards a normal distribution centred about the peak (i.e. mode) of the distribution of the $X_i$, this obviously corresponds to the mean for normal distributions but I am interested in non-symmetric distributions where this is not the case. So I am asking if there exists some function $H$ s.t.

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \alpha(H(X_1,...,X_n) - \phi) = \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2),
$$

where $\alpha$ is some number which might depend on $n$ and $\phi$ is the mode of the distribution from which the $X_i$ are drawn.

Comment: i couldn't get what you are asking -- the CLT does not depend on the underlying distribution of the $X_i$, it can be asymmetric or even discrete.

Comment: My question is asking whether by taking some other combination of the $X_i$ we can converge towards a normal distribution centred around the underlying distributions mode rather than mean. Also the central limit theorem does depend on the mean and s.d. of the underlying distribution of the $X_i$ and it is in this sense that I'm asking. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: yes, thank you very much

Comment: The question is cumbersome because such a function trivially exists ($\alpha=\sqrt n$ and $H$ outputs $\phi+n^{-1}S_n-\mu$). Is your goal estimation of the mode? If so, you can do it since the empirical distribution converges to the actual distribution and you'll probably get some kind of a normal convergence for continuous single moded distributions.

Comment: This is a very good point, however, I should have said that I am not assuming I know the modal value, I am hoping to be able to apply this in order to estimate the modal value, plus make noise on measurements look gaussian by applying something similar to the estimate $ \frac{1}{n}\sum_i X_i  \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\frac{\sigma ^2}{n})$.

Comment: @A.S., I think that the question is to construct a statistic. That is, it should not depend neither on $\mu$ nor on $\phi$. Now concerning the question, it is not easy. Estimating the mode consistently, i.e. constructing an estimator $H(X) = H(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ such that $H(X)\to \phi$, $n\to\infty$, is already a hard task, and there are many methods. Usually the idea is to use a kernel estimator to estimate the density and then find its maximum. But there are many caveats, and it is hard to explain everything here. You should search for mode estimators on Google Scholar.

Comment: I would be surprised if there was a good general mode estimator which had an unbiased normal distribution as its limit, just by considering a sample drawn from an exponential distributed random variable where none of the observations will be below the mode. A random variable with a uniform distribution may not provide any convergence, while one with a discrete distribution may have part of the the distribution of the estimator with a positive probability of $0$.

Comment: If I wanted a mode estimator from R, I might use something like the following `den <- density(obs); mode_estimate <- den$x[den$y == max(den$y)] `

Comment: Thank you all for you very helpful comments, I'll go and take a look at mode estimators as it seems this is what I will need if I'm going to be able to do this. Thanks again!

Comment: @zhora I inferred that much, but wanted to point out that OP's attempt to formalize his quest (formalization of which included a somewhat arbitrary condition for the statistic to be asymptotically normal) instead of stating it in plain English ("how can I construct a statistic for / estimate the mode") is a prime example of X-Y problem.